# C# code issue working on player movement and stamina system in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on building a custom character movement system for my unity project but I seem to be having some problems with my code, no errors appear in the console and what I am trying to do is create a timer for a stamina system that will fatigued the player overtime and also a recharge system before the player can run again.

The main issue is when I print the values of the current stamina multiple timers are being ran, also the values are not going up appropriately as they should
any help would be appreciated

Thankyou!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    CharacterController characterControl;
    [SerializeField] float walkSpeed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] float sprintSpeed = 15f;
    [Header("Stamina")]
    [SerializeField] float maxStaminaDecreaseTimer = .5f;
    [SerializeField] float maxStaminaIncreaseTime = 1.0f;
    [SerializeField] float speedChange = 15f;
    float maxStamina = 100f;
    float currentStamina;
    float currentSpeed;
    bool isSprinting = false;
    float staminaDecrease = 0.5f;
    float staminaIncrease = 1.0f;
    //Timer System 
    float currentStaminaDecreaseTimer;
    float currentStaminaIncreaseTimer;
    // Movement System
    void Start() {
        characterControl = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        currentStaminaDecreaseTimer = maxStaminaDecreaseTimer;
        currentStaminaIncreaseTimer = maxStaminaIncreaseTime;
        currentSpeed = walkSpeed;
        currentStamina = maxStamina;
    }

    void Update() {
        MovePlayer();
        StaminaSystem();
    }

    void MovePlayer() {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveSide = transform.right * horizontal * currentSpeed;
        Vector3 moveForward = transform.forward * vertical * currentSpeed;

        characterControl.SimpleMove(moveSide * Time.deltaTime);
        characterControl.SimpleMove(moveForward * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void StaminaSystem() {
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("Sprint")) {
            if (!isSprinting && currentStamina > 0) {
                currentSpeed = sprintSpeed;
                isSprinting = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (isSprinting) {
                currentSpeed = walkSpeed;
                isSprinting = false;
            }
        }

        if (isSprinting) {

            if (currentStaminaDecreaseTimer <= 0) {
                currentStamina -= staminaDecrease;
                currentStaminaDecreaseTimer = maxStaminaDecreaseTimer;
            }

            currentStaminaDecreaseTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        } else if (!isSprinting) {

            if (currentStaminaIncreaseTimer <= 0) {
                currentStamina += staminaIncrease;
                currentStaminaIncreaseTimer = maxStaminaIncreaseTime;
            }

            if (currentStamina > maxStamina) {
                currentStamina = maxStamina;
            }
            print(currentStamina);

            currentStaminaIncreaseTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine when I run it. That is, `currentStamina` decreases according to the decrease timer and decrease amount when I hold down the "sprint" button, and increases accordingly when I release the "sprint" button. What's the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for all the responses i really appreciate them, i was so worked up in my code thinking it was the problem i never realized i had two of the same scripts tied to the game object which in return was giving me interesting behavior XD, well i guess it happens to the best of us!